# xcodebuild archive configuration not work

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, archive, xcodebuild

I want to use xcodebuild to archive one scheme with 3 different configurations, but the configuration is never changed with archive action.

Here is the content in .sh

```
xcodebuild -workspace myApp.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -scheme myApp -configuration Distribution clean archive

xcodebuild -workspace myApp.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -scheme myApp -configuration Inhouse clean archive

xcodebuild -workspace myApp.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -scheme myApp -configuration Release clean archive
```

update: build action works fine

```
xcodebuild -workspace myApp.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -scheme myApp -configuration Distribution clean build

xcodebuild -workspace myApp.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -scheme myApp -configuration Inhouse clean build

xcodebuild -workspace myApp.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -scheme myApp -configuration Release clean build
```

I am using Xcode4.5/iOS6.0, It works fine with build action(configuration changes each xcodebuild run), any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration for archive action has no effect, maybe it's a bug of xcodebuild.

In order to change the configuration of archive, I write a shell script change the configuration of scheme each time before run archive command.

May not be the best solution, but solve the problem.

Here is the code:

```
#! /bin/sh

# Define Scheme name
PACKAGE_PROJECT_NAME="MyApp"
PACKAGE_SCHEME_NAME="MyApp"

# Get Username
PACKAGE_USER_NAME="$(whoami)"

# Scheme Path
PACKAGE_SCHEME_DIR="$SRCROOT/${PACKAGE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/${PACKAGE_USER_NAME}.xcuserdatad/xcschemes"
PACKAGE_SCHEME_PATH="${PACKAGE_SCHEME_DIR}/${PACKAGE_SCHEME_NAME}.xcscheme"

echo "PACKAGE_SCHEME_PATH = ${PACKAGE_SCHEME_PATH}"

# Set Configuration
# WARNING: BACKUP_CONFIGURATION MUST be same with build configuration of archive action in MyApp scheme
BACKUP_CONFIGURATION="Distribution"

# WARNING: Archive name of archive action in MyApp scheme MUST be set explicitly.
# WARNING: BACKUP_ARCHIVENAME MUST be same with archive name of archive action in MyApp scheme
BACKUP_ARCHIVENAME="MyAppArchive"

echo "BACKUP_CONFIGURATION = ${BACKUP_CONFIGURATION}"
echo "BACKUP_ARCHIVENAME = ${BACKUP_ARCHIVENAME}"

# -------------------------------Archive Distribution---------------------------------------
# Set Configuration
OLD_CONFIGURATION="${BACKUP_CONFIGURATION}"
NEW_CONFIGURATION="Distribution"
OLD_ARCHIVENAME="${BACKUP_ARCHIVENAME}"
NEW_ARCHIVENAME="${PACKAGE_SCHEME_NAME}_${NEW_CONFIGURATION}"

# Clean
xcodebuild -workspace ${PACKAGE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -scheme ${PACKAGE_SCHEME_NAME} -configuration ${NEW_CONFIGURATION} clean

# Change archive configuration
sed -i .bak "/<ArchiveAction/,/<\/ArchiveAction>/{s/\"${OLD_CONFIGURATION}\"/\"${NEW_CONFIGURATION}\"/;s/\"${OLD_ARCHIVENAME}\"/\"${NEW_ARCHIVENAME}\"/;}" ${PACKAGE_SCHEME_PATH}

# Archive
xcodebuild -workspace ${PACKAGE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -scheme ${PACKAGE_SCHEME_NAME} archive

# -------------------------------Archive Inhouse------------------------------------------
# Set Configuration
OLD_CONFIGURATION="${NEW_CONFIGURATION}"
NEW_CONFIGURATION="Inhouse"
OLD_ARCHIVENAME="${NEW_ARCHIVENAME}"
NEW_ARCHIVENAME="${PACKAGE_SCHEME_NAME}_${NEW_CONFIGURATION}"

# Clean
xcodebuild -workspace ${PACKAGE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -scheme ${PACKAGE_SCHEME_NAME} -configuration ${NEW_CONFIGURATION} clean

# Change archive configuration
sed -i .bak "/<ArchiveAction/,/<\/ArchiveAction>/{s/\"${OLD_CONFIGURATION}\"/\"${NEW_CONFIGURATION}\"/;s/\"${OLD_ARCHIVENAME}\"/\"${NEW_ARCHIVENAME}\"/;}" ${PACKAGE_SCHEME_PATH}

# Archive
xcodebuild -workspace ${PACKAGE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -scheme ${PACKAGE_SCHEME_NAME} archive

# -------------------------------Archive Adhoc-------------------------------------------
# Set Configuration
OLD_CONFIGURATION="${NEW_CONFIGURATION}"
NEW_CONFIGURATION="Release"
OLD_ARCHIVENAME="${NEW_ARCHIVENAME}"
NEW_ARCHIVENAME="${PACKAGE_SCHEME_NAME}_${NEW_CONFIGURATION}"

# Clean
xcodebuild -workspace ${PACKAGE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -scheme ${PACKAGE_SCHEME_NAME} -configuration ${NEW_CONFIGURATION} clean

# Change archive configuration
sed -i .bak "/<ArchiveAction/,/<\/ArchiveAction>/{s/\"${OLD_CONFIGURATION}\"/\"${NEW_CONFIGURATION}\"/;s/\"${OLD_ARCHIVENAME}\"/\"${NEW_ARCHIVENAME}\"/;}" ${PACKAGE_SCHEME_PATH}

# Archive
xcodebuild -workspace ${PACKAGE_PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -sdk iphoneos -scheme ${PACKAGE_SCHEME_NAME} archive

# ------------------------------Restore Configuration-------------------------------------
sed -i .bak "/<ArchiveAction/,/<\/ArchiveAction>/{s/\"${NEW_CONFIGURATION}\"/\"${BACKUP_CONFIGURATION}\"/;s/\"${NEW_ARCHIVENAME}\"/\"${BACKUP_ARCHIVENAME}\"/;}" ${PACKAGE_SCHEME_PATH}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `--scheme` option, the configuration is overridden by the settings in the Scheme itself. You will need to create 3 different schemes and configure each to use the appropriate configuration for the Archive action:

[image]

Alternatively you can not bother with schemes at all, and use the `--target` and `--configuration` switches on the command line directly.

Comment: The build action works fine(see my update), use `-target` the archive action won't run, get `unsupported build action archive` error.